# Proving that a function is a probability density function

Tags: probability, density-function

Let $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ be a random vector with joint density $$\begin{cases} 8x_1x_2x_3, & x_1,x_2,x_3 \in (0,1) \\ 0, & x_1,x_2,x_3 \in (0,1)^c \end{cases}$$

Let $Y_1 =X_1$, $Y_2=X_1X_2$ and $Y_3=X_1X_2X_3$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$. I have managed to find the density of $Y$, which is $f_Y(y)=\frac{8y_3}{y_1y_2}$, but now i must prove that this really is a density function and i'm having some troubles with the boundaries of the triple integral. Any hint? Thanks!

Comment: What is the meaning of exponent $c$ in $0, x_1,x_2,x_3 \in (0,1)^c$ ? Complement ? Furthermore, why is $0$ present there ?

Comment: It's the complement

Comment: Therefore, you mean that the $x_k>1$ ?

Comment: Well, u can thins that if $x_k \not\in (0,1)$, then it is $0$.

Comment: Now I understand...

Answer (score 1):

The conditions were

$$0<X_1<1\\
0<X_2<1\\
0<X_3<1$$

If we solve for $X_1,X_2,X_3$ in terms of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ we get

$$X_1=Y_1\\
X_2=Y_2/X_1=Y_2/Y_1\\
X_3=Y_3/(X_1X_2)=Y_3/Y_1(Y_1/Y_2)=Y_3/Y_2$$

Thus the limits are

$$0<Y_1<1\\
0<Y_2/Y_1<1\\
0<Y_3/Y_2<1$$

which can be written as

$$0<Y_1<1\\
0<Y_2<Y_1\\
0<Y_3<Y_2$$

Thus you could integrate as

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{y_1}\int_0^{y_2} f(y_1,y_2,y_3)dy_3dy_2dy_1$$